# SharePoint: Wrong Date in Word Template's Quick Part

Tags: date, templates, sharepoint, ms-word, content-type

I have a library with custom content type with .docx template.

I have a 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' fields in the content type which are mapped to quick parts in .docx template.

When I change the values of these two fields in item properties, it updates the values in document as well (as it's supposed to be).

**PROBLEM**

The values in the document are always one day off.

If for example I set the date to 15/04/2016, it shows 14/04/2016 on the document.

How can I make them equal?

The time zones and everything seems to be fine on SharePoint and on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue is being caused by the way SharePoint stores date and time values. From the [SharePoint MSDN article on Converting Date and Time Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms197282.aspx):

> Microsoft SharePoint Foundation stores date and time values in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format, and almost all date and time values that are returned by members of the object model are in UTC format.

So when you enter a date and time into SharePoint in local time, SharePoint stores that information in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). But when the mapped content control in Word retrieves the date/time value it receives the UTC equivalent of whatever your local date and time is (SharePoint itself automatically converts date and time values to your local time when displaying that information within its own user interface).

I think the best way to solve this would be to create calculated fields that are not displayed. The calculated fields would take the input date/time values from your 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' fields in the content type and correct them for your local UTC offset. You could then map the corrected calculated values to Quick Parts in your Word document.

Comment: Thanks @joeschwa , I had this solution in my mind in case I won't resolve this in other way... So I suppose there's nothing else I can do? It's starnge because I can't find any articles about this issue... It looks like a common thing working with quick parts

Comment: Sorry to say there doesn't seem to be another option. UTC creates a host of problems anywhere SharePoint date/time data is used externally. The MSDN post I listed is the only official Microsoft mention I've seen referring to this. However there are blog posts. Here are two: [ClientSight SP Blog Entry on UTC](http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/09/sharepoint-stores-dates-in-utc-time/) and [Francois Verbeeck on SP UTC](https://francoisverbeeck.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/sharepoint-tip-of-the-day-be-careful-when-wor/).

Comment: That's all I could find as well... :D Thanks!